# Edit privileges vs approving edits

Tags: bug, editing

I have enough rep to directly edit other users posts. But if someone else makes an edit that requires approval, my approval isn't enough to get the edit accepted.

Not a big deal at all, but this seems inconsistent. If I'm trusted enough to make edits myself, shouldn't that extend to approving edits made by other users?

Motivated by my trying to approve a simple tag addition to this question:

[Create table with circles around words and hiding some of the grid lines in Emacs Org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80418/262)

I can't even edit the post myself at this point, as new edits can't be made while an existing edit is waiting for approval.